# Libgdx | Dynamically Generate Tiledmap

Tags: java, android, libgdx, desktop

I have set up and got a tiledmap rendering successfully from tmx file. My game is a top down 2D maze game. I want to move to randomly generating the tiles, and I have the algorithm. The only problem is that I'm not sure how I can :

1) Dynamically create tiledmap
2) I will somehow need to set the rotation correctly in the algorithm of each tile.
3) Not only that, but I will need to determine which sprites to be drawn on each tile I generate. For instance, I have corner pieces, straight pieces, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. With your algorithm.
2. Why do you need rotation? You want to rotate corner pieces? Then simply code that yourself.
3. Same as `2`, determine what tile needs to be drawn yourself.

What I usually do is give each type of floor a unique number and if you have multiple floors for variation give these a unique number too. Then your alghorithm needs to fill a map with types, then you can randomly insert unique floors of that type.

When your alghorithm is finished you can calculate corners in a 2nd pass. If you have a wall where only W, NW, and N is open then its a wall corner going from S to E. If you have a single image for all corners that is going from S to W then you just need to flip it horizontally or turn it 270 / -90 degrees. You need to calculate all these things yourself, and yes it's tedious work with a lot of if statements or switches.

I suggest you start small, just have a square block for a wall type and continue from there. So just create a map with booleans first, 0 = floow and 1 = wall. Later you can extend it further. You can add a lot of variations, I have been working on a tileset with 56 different tile types and these all needed to have 1 or more variations as well.

Comment: Yes I understand with my algorithm. I just dont understand how to actually dynamically create a tiledmap. I know how to load tiledmaps and use them, but how do I create a tiledmap with code?

Comment: You run the alghorithm on a data structure and interpret it's values. let's say you have a 2D array with `1` and `0` then for each `0` you could draw a wall and for each `1` you can draw a floor.

Comment: Yes, I understand that too. My question is how to create a libgdx TiledMap class dynamically.

Comment: @Wyatt Why do that? Why not create your own? I never used Tiled it does not work how I want.

Comment: I have tried creating my own, but when I do, rendering 100x100 (10,000) tiles creates horrible lag, even on pc. I'm not sure how tiled does it so efficiently.

Comment: @Wyatt Then that should be your question or look up how to draw it efficiently. Anyway, you know your `camera position`, the `viewport width/height` and the `tile dimensions`. Seems like a easy formula to know which tiles to draw and then you are probably only drawing about 200 tiles. So calculate which `X.Y` you need to start drawing and which `X,Y` you need to stop drawing and only loop over those numbers instead of the whole array.